# Use each Power Query JSON array item as parameters to the next Query

Tags: json, excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have some REST API endpoints, and I want to fetch a specific view of the data to Excel.

Let say I want to create a table with `UserName` and it `Age`. To get this data I need to do two requests:

`GET /users` will return

```
[
  {
    "name": "User1",
    "id": 3
  }
  ...
]
```

Then I need to take the `name` of each item in the result of `GET /users` for the `UserName` column, and for each `id`, I need to do the next request:

`GET /users/3` will return

```
{
  "age": 52,
  "address": "xyz"
}
```

And I need to take the `age` and set it as the second column, right after the `name` from the first request.

Can I do it? How? (With *Excel Power Query*, of course)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `each` construct in PowerQuery. Rough scaffolding below:

```
let Source = ... ,    
Age = Table.AddColumn(Source, "AgeColumnName", each Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://example.com/api/users/" & [id]"))),
in Age
```